# New Google Patents site, which URL to use?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, hyperlinks

The typical method of linking to Google Patents has been:

https://www.google.com/patents/US20130219479A1

[image: Older Google Patents]

However, since the recent update to Google Patents, there is a new view available:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130219479A1/en?q=login

(and apparently linking as https://patents.google.com/patent/US20130219479A1 does not work).

[image: Newer Google Patents]

This newer URL does not provide a link to Ask Patents (at least, nothing that is immediately apparent).

Should we continue to use the older style of URL, or allow the newer ones as well (or instead of)?

**Update:** Apparently, this was part of the [update from July 16, 2015](http://googlepublicpolicy.blogspot.com/2015/07/good-patents-support-innovation-while.html). The oddity is that a Google search for a patent number still resolves to the (www) site. There are a [few other mentions](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6261372?hl=en) of the new site which mention the www.google.com/patents site as the "old" site:

> You can still access the [old Google Patents](https://www.google.com/patents) and the [Prior Art Finder](https://www.google.com/patents/related).

There are several side-effects to losing the "Discuss this patent" button: (1) Ask Patents will lose visibility (and traffic); (2) The tagging scheme with patent number tags would lose some relevance.

Also: If the "old" site is ever retired, the links on this site will break. This integration was something that was planned by SE prior to the launch of this site. The SE employees responsible for this community should be aware of these changes so they can plan accordingly (and perhaps re-examine/renew their business relationship with Google, in order to avoid such breakage).

Additionally, someone should verify if the patent summary sidebar is dependent on any functionality from the "old" site, and whether there is a newer API that replaces it.

Comment: The latter one 404s for me unless I pin on `/en`. Is it still in beta?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Not sure, Google usually labels their beta sites. Today is the first I've seen it, from a post in the review queue.

Comment: Yeah. I'd be tempted to stick with how things are (people who post new links, no worries, people who post old ones, no worries). I doubt Google will keep both around forever, and I suspect they'll all redirect to the same place once they're comfortable with it all. So I'd probably hold off on making any substantial system changes until they've had a good chance to do that.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I agree, but I figured its best to at least get it out here so everyone is aware of it. I'll check the Google product forums and will update the question if I find out anything else.

Comment: Yep, for sure. Thanks for bringing it up. If nothing else, it's nice to see they're still actively developing Google Patents! :) I'm happy to see a revamped UI for it.

Comment: Turns out, they refer to the www site as the "old site". That could be telling for the integration between Google Patents and Ask Patents.

Comment: Ah, good find. It's interesting to see such a heavy emphasis put on prior art searches, and it seems like that could actually be a good place to link to Ask Patents, unlike the legacy "Discuss this Patent" button. But unfortunately, in any event, it's on secret that the original AP initiative didn't pick up the long-term support that everyone was hoping for, so I can't blame them too much for failing to include the button in an update. This might also lend to a bit more stability for Ask Patents to let us grow without as many direct moderation concerns--just a silver lining.